# React - this is undefined when binding function to component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this

I have this code. I imported some components from Semantic UI.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, Image, Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react'
```

I am trying to call function when error (404) appears when loading image.

```
export default class HotelCards extends React.Component {
  // constructor
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
  }
  // state
  state = {}
```

This is the function I'd like to call: (not that if I log `this` inside render function I get instance of current class)

```
  handleError() {
    console.log(this);
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.props.hotels) return null;
    return (
        <Grid doubling stackable columns="4" className="cards-container">
        {
            this.props.hotels.map(function(e, i) {
                return (
                  <Grid.Column key={i} className="card-column">
                    <Card>
```

From this element:

```
                      <Image src={e.hotel.image} onError={this.handleError} />
                    </Card>
                  </Grid.Column>
                )
            })
        }
      </Grid>
    );
  }//render
}//class
```

However I get error that `this` is `undefined`.

```
TypeError: this is undefined
Stack trace:
render/<@http://localhost:1337/app/bundle.js:63883:92
...
```

In vanilla JavaScript my approach for this would be

```
<img src="image.png" onError="this.onerror=null;this.src='/placeholder.jpg';" />
```

How do I bind this function to component properly?

Comment: I've just noticed that you're not passing arrow function to `map`, so the current value of `this` is lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok guys, I found the reason why `this` is `undefined`.

It is because these stuff happen inside `.map` method, so I had to bind `this` to it like this:

```
this.props.hotels.map(function(e, i) {
 ...
}, this)
```

or as @apendua commented, by using arrow function so `this` doesn't get lost:

```
 this.props.hotels.map((e, i) => {
     ...
  })
```

Answer (score 3):

The typical approach is using the so called "late binding", i.e.

```
constructor() {
    // ...
    this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
}

handleError() {
    console.log('THIS', this);
}
```

The reason your code did not work was because your fat arrow is binding to the context in which your class is being defined.

Alternatively, you could also bind at the rendering level as suggested in another answer, so:

```
<Image src={e.hotel.image} onError={this.handleError.bind(this)} />
```

However, the problem with that solution is that it produces a new handler function on every call to your `render` method, which can (but don't have to) negatively influence your rendering performance if you're using some kind of property equality testing optimization techniques.

Comment: I tried both approaches, but still get  same `this` is `undefined` error.

Comment: Can you identify at which point the error is thrown? Maybe it's not inside the `handleError` method?

Comment: Hello thanks for help, the core problem was in `map` method, I had to bind `this` to it.

Comment: Great. All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Fat arrow functions as methods in a class are not supported in ES6, so you'd first have to define *handError* as method like this:

```
handleError() {
    console.log('test');
}
```

and you should be able to bind to it so it can use *this* if required:

```
 <Image src={e.hotel.image} onError={this.handleError.bind(this} />
```

To void the *bind* in your render function (which in some case can have performance) you can do the binding in your constructor function:

```
this.handleError = this.handleError.bind(this);
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried to use `.bind(this)` method, and I get same error as before. (`this` is `undefined`)

Comment: May be because it doesn't recognise the fat arrow definition for handleError? Try a 'standard' method defintion.

Comment: Even after adding binding to constructor, `this` is still `undefined`. I also changed handleError method definition.

Comment: If you remove 'this' from the console log does the error go away? (Need to identify which this is not bound.)

Comment: The core problem was inside `map` method, I had to bind `this` to it.

Answer (score 1):

@kunok : nice you found your answer. Arrow function ( => ) keep the *this* context same as enclosing function.

Answer (score 0):

Add this.state is inside component the constructor.